# viewstate MAC failed in asp.net 2.0 while postback the page

Tags: macos, validation, asp.net-2.0, viewstate

I have a website in asp.net 2.0 with default membership provider. It was fine til yesterday.
When i add custom google search box in my website now i am getting the same error 
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
I found few solutions in web that if we installed .net 3.5 with service pack1 then we will get such a errors and either uninstall 3.5 or install service pack 2 with Asp.net 2.0 to resolve the issues.
ASp.net 3.5 was installed in my pc so that i uninstalled it.but no success.
Please advice me a solution to avoid such a problem in asp.net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom google search box is a form on the page. You now have two forms and you are only supposed to have one in order to maintain your viewstate.